# Lambda value for BoxCox transformation in time series analysis

Tags: time-series, data-transformation

I was reading the online version of *Forecasting: principles and practice* by Rob J Hyndman and George Athana­sopou­los. I found this sentence about STL decomposition and the BoxCox transformation:

> "Decompositions some way between additive and multiplicative can be obtained using a Box-Cox transformation of the data with 0<λ<1. A value of λ=0 corresponds to the multiplicative decomposition while λ=1 is equivalent to an additive decomposition."

My question is: why is it just lambda in that range could be a valid option? Why couldn't lambda equal -0.5 or 2?

Comment: You're right; it can.  You just couldn't interpret a $\lambda$ outside that range as being "between" additive and multiplicative.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to look at [When (and why) should you take the log of a distribution (of numbers)?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/18844/when-and-why-should-you-take-the-log-of-a-distribution-of-numbers/18852#18852) which discusses power transforms. Unwarranted or incorrect transformations including differences should be studiously avoided as they are often an ill-fashioned /ill-conceived  attempt to deal with unidentified anomalies/level shifts/time trends or changes in parameters or changes in error variance

A classic example of this is discussed starting at slide 60 here http://www.autobox.com/cms/index.php/afs-university/intro-to-forecasting/doc_download/53-capabilities-presentation where three pulse anomalies (untreated) led to an unwarranted log transformation by early researchers. Unfortunately some of our current researchers are still making the same mistake.

The issue here ( as suggested by the op) is to be very wary of assumptions.